How to obtain the result of Ott-Antonsen ansatz of the classic Kuramoto model
This is my derivation process：
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} +\frac{\partial (f*\frac{\partial \theta }{\partial t})} {\partial \theta } = 0.$
Then $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta }\left(f \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\mathrm{d} t}\right) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta } \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\mathrm{d} t} + f \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta }\left(\frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\mathrm{d} t}\right),$
where  $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \sum_{n=-\infty }^{n=+\infty} n\alpha ^{n-1}e^{in\theta}\frac{\partial{\alpha} }{\partial{t} }+\alpha^{n}ine^{in\theta }\frac{\partial{\theta}  }{\partial{t}}$
$f \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta }\left(\frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\mathrm{d} t}\right) = \sum_{n=-\infty }^{n=+\infty} \alpha ^{n}e^{in\theta} * (-\frac{k}{2} ( r e^{-i\theta} + \overline{r} e^{i\theta} )) . $
And $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta } * \frac{\partial  \theta}{\partial t} = \sum_{n=-\infty }^{n=+\infty} in\alpha ^{n}e^{in\theta}* \frac{\partial{\theta}  }{\partial{t}}$.
Finally, I get a result:
$\sum_{n=-\infty }^{n=+\infty} \alpha ^{n-1}e^{in\theta}[n\frac{\partial \alpha }{\partial t}+2i\alpha n\omega+(\alpha nk-\frac{k\alpha}{2})re^{-i\theta} -(\alpha nk+\frac{k\alpha}{2})\overline{r}e^{i\theta }]=0$
How can i get $ \frac{\partial \alpha }{\partial t} +(k/2)(r\alpha^2-\overline{r})+i\omega \alpha =0 $?
Feel free to point out my mistakes.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
